# Decomposition of an asymmetric 'postive definite' matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition

For an arbitrary square matrix $L$ whose symmetric part $\frac{L+L^\mathrm{T}}{2}\succcurlyeq0$ is positive semidefinite, can one always find a decomposition $L=U^\mathrm{T}QU$ where $U=U^\mathrm{T}\succcurlyeq0$ and asymmetric $Q$ has $\frac{Q+Q^\mathrm{T}}{2}\succ0$?

The answer seems to be positive, but I still would like to ask about it.

Note, here, that '$L$ is asymmetric' means $L\neq L^\mathrm{T}$.

Comment: by asymmetric do you mean not symmetric or antisymmetric?  Also you use $\succcurlyeq$ but you say positive definite, which do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. 'Asymmetric' implies 'not symmetric'. I've revised the question. The question assumes that $\frac{L+L^\mathrm{T}}{2}$ is positive semidefinite.